# Clojure - tests with components strategy

Tags: unit-testing, testing, clojure, clojure-testing

I am implementing an app using Stuart Sierra component. As he states in the README :

> Having a coherent way to set up and tear down all the state associated
>   with an application enables rapid development cycles without
>   restarting the JVM. It can also make unit tests faster and more
>   independent, since the cost of creating and starting a system is low
>   enough that every test can create a new instance of the system.

What would be the preferred strategy here ? Something similar to JUnit oneTimeSetUp / oneTimeTearDown , or really between each test (similar to setUp / tearDown) ?

And if between each test, is there a simple way to start/stop a system for *all* tests (before and after) without repeating the code every time ?

**Edit** : sample code to show what I mean

```
(defn test-component-lifecycle [f]
  (println "Setting up test-system")
  (let [s (system/new-test-system)]
    (f s) ;; I cannot pass an argument here ( https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/test.clj#L718 ), so how can I pass a system in parameters of a test ?
    (println "Stopping test-system")
    (component/stop s)))

(use-fixtures :once test-component-lifecycle)
```

**Note** : I am talking about unit-testing here.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a macro, which takes a system-map and starts all components before running tests and stop all components after testing.

For example:

```
(ns de.hh.new-test
 (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
           [com.stuartsierra.component :as component]))


;;; Macro to start and stop component
(defmacro with-started-components [bindings & body]
    `(let [~(bindings 0) (component/start ~(bindings 1))]
       (try
          (let* ~(destructure (vec (drop 2 bindings)))
            ~@body)
       (catch Exception e1#)
       (finally
         (component/stop ~(bindings 0))))))

;; Test Component
(defprotocol Action
  (do-it [self]))

(defrecord TestComponent [state]
   component/Lifecycle
   (start [self]
      (println "====> start")
      (assoc self :state (atom state)))
   (stop [self]
      (println "====> stop"))

   Action
    (do-it [self]
       (println "====> do action")
       @(:state self)))

;: TEST
(deftest ^:focused component-test
   (with-started-components
      [system (component/system-map :test-component (->TestComponent"startup-state"))
       test-component (:test-component system)]

    (is (= "startup-state" (do-it test-component)))))
```

Running Test you should see the out put like this

```
====> start
====> do action
====> stop

Ran 1 tests containing 1 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```